# Calling managed COM from unmanaged code : SAFEARRAY

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, com

I have a COM component written in VB.net. Interface for this COM Component is

```
Public Interface IEdge
    Function FooFunc() As Integer
    Function Exec(ByVal modelName As String, ByVal Params As Object()) As Object
    Sub Foo()
    Sub Fooint(ByVal a As Integer)
End Interface
```

I am using Type Library of this COM component in Native C++ code using

```
#import "..\Edge.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
```

The C++ code for Main is

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);  //Initialize all COM Components

    ICOMEdgePtr myEdge;
    HRESULT hRes =   myEdge.CreateInstance(CLSID_COMEdge);
    if (hRes == S_OK)
    {
        VARIANT lResult ;
        BSTR str;

        myEdge->Foo();
        myEdge->Fooint(1234);
        long abc = 0;
        myEdge->FooFunc(&abc);

        SAFEARRAYBOUND aBound[2];
        aBound[1].cElements = 2;
        aBound[1].lLbound = 0;
        SAFEARRAY* sf = SafeArrayCreate(VT_INT, 1, &aBound[1]);

        long index1=0;
        int val1=20;
        SafeArrayPutElement(sf, &index1, &val1);

        long index2=1;
        int val2=30;
        SafeArrayPutElement(sf, &index2, &val2);

        myEdge->Exec(L"Add", sf, &lResult);
        //Using lResult after this  
    }

    CoUninitialize (); 
    return 0;
}
```

I am able to Call `FooFunc()`, `Foo()`, `Fooint()`.

But I am unable to call `Exec` function, it doesn't show any error, no crash is reported.

For a test, I have consumed this COM component in VB.net (using `CreateObject(CLSID)`) and Exec can be called from there. I need to call this from Native C++.

I suspect that there is some problem with the `SafeArray` and `Object()` conversion. Is the Interface definition wrong?

I tried with `System.Array`, `<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.SafeArray)>` but nothing solves the problem. I have put up a `MsgBox()` as first statement of `Exec` definition so that I can know if `Exec` gets called.

Comment: This code lacks all required error checking.  Which tells you what you did wrong.  A SafeArray of VTINT only matches Integer() in VB.NET

Comment: @HansPassant Trying now for Integer()... Actual C++ code has exception handling, but that doesn't catches any thing related to this.

Comment: @HansPassant using VT_VARIANT instead of VT_INT. Everything working fine, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the suggestions given by `Hans Passant` I am able to use SAFEARRAY.

I am consuming Dotnet based COM component in C++. Finally I have changed the C++ code to stay safe with COM.

I have replaced `VARIANT` with `CComVariant`, `BSTR` with `CComBSTR` and `SAFEARRAY` with `CComSafeArray`.

Now the Main's code look like:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);  //Initialize all COM Components

    ICOMEdgePtr myEdge;
    HRESULT hRes =   myEdge.CreateInstance(CLSID_COMEdge);
    if (hRes == S_OK)
    {
        CComVariant lResult ;
        CComSafeArray<VARIANT> arr(2,0);
        arr[0] = 20;
        arr[1] = 30;

        CComBSTR methodName;
        methodName = L"Add";

        myEdge->Exec(methodName, arr, &lResult);
        wprintf(L"The result is %d\n", lResult.intVal);
        //Using lResult after this
    }

    CoUninitialize (); 
    return 0;
}
```